# What do these Novell registry entries do? What happens if I delete them?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, group-policy

The following reg folders are in Computer -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> Novell -> ZCM -> Group Policy

[image: The Reg Folders]

What are they, what do they do, and what will happen if I delete them?

Comment: All I know is they are part of Zenworks, the suite of Novell for computer systems management.
You shouldn't remove them, unless you have uninstalled Zenworks.

Comment: Would deleting them damage my system, or just the Zenworks suite?

Comment: Mainly the damage will be on Zenworks, but keep in mind that Zenworks is able to limit user actions as `change wallpaper` or `ìnstall new hardware`, for example. So your system could have conflicts when executing some actions.